# Outmoded word for "next Tuesday"

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, time, archaicisms

I am writing an email and wanted to refer to this coming Tuesday. The phrase "Tuesday est" popped into my mind (something Miss Marple might have said) but when I googled it I could find no reference. I have a feeling that 'est' isn't correct, but there is a word or I presume an abreviation that sounds like it that means next. Could you please tell me what it is?

Aha! I have just had a brain wave, it isn't 'est', it's 'inst'. Is that right? What does it stand for?

Comment: "Tuesday next" would mean the coming Tuesday.

Comment: or Tuesday week

Comment: @mgb: "Tuesday week" means the day exactly a week after the coming Tuesday.

Answer (score 6):

*Inst* is an abbreviation of the Latin 'instante mense', meaning the current month. *Prox* ('proxime mense') means next month and *ult* ('ultimo mense') means last month. These terms were once used in correspondence, but are used now, if at all, only by the terminally abstruse.

Comment: And even then, it could not have been 'Tuesday *inst*', only '25th *inst*'.

Comment: @TimLymington: Yes, quite right.